# delete first array element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array structure like this:

```
$data=    Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [A] => BANK
                [B] => IFSC
                [C] => MICR
                [D] => BRANCH
                [E] => ADDRESS
                [F] => CONTACT
                [G] => CITY
                [H] => DISTRICT
                [I] => STATE
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [A] => ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED
                [B] => ABHY0065001
                [C] => 400065001
                [D] => RTGS-HO
                [E] => ABHYUDAYA BANK BLDG., B.NO.71, NEHRU NAGAR, KURLA (E), MUMBAI-400024
                [F] => 25260173
                [G] => MUMBAI
                [H] => GREATER MUMBAI
                [I] => MAHARASHTRA
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [A] => ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED
                [B] => ABHY0065002
                [C] => 400065002
                [D] => ABHYUDAYA NAGAR
                [E] => ABHYUDAYA EDUCATION SOCIETY, OPP. BLDG. NO. 18, ABHYUDAYA NAGAR, KALACHOWKY, MUMBAI - 400033
                [F] => 24702643
                [G] => MUMBAI
                [H] => GREATER MUMBAI
                [I] => MAHARASHTRA
            )
    )
```

I want to delete the first index,and reindex the array from 0.

I tried the following:
$newData = array_splice($data,0,1);

but it gives the following output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => BANK
            [B] => IFSC
            [C] => MICR
            [D] => BRANCH
            [E] => ADDRESS
            [F] => CONTACT
            [G] => CITY
            [H] => DISTRICT
            [I] => STATE
        )

)
```

The Part of array that I want to remove is the one that stays and the remaining is deleted.

Comment: `$newData = array_slice($data,1);`

Comment: thank you .This did the job

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_slice($array, 1)`.

```
$result = array_slice($data, 1);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one.. hope this will help you out. Here we are using `key` function which will return first `key`, Here we are unsetting `top index` and returning `array_values`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785007)

```
unset($data[key($data)]);//unsetting the top index
$data=array_values($data);//returning array_values
print_r($data);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED
            [B] => ABHY0065001
            [C] => 400065001
            [D] => RTGS-HO
            [E] => ABHYUDAYA BANK BLDG., B.NO.71, NEHRU NAGAR, KURLA (E), MUMBAI-400024
            [F] => 25260173
            [G] => MUMBAI
            [H] => GREATER MUMBAI
            [I] => MAHARASHTRA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED
            [B] => ABHY0065002
            [C] => 400065002
            [D] => ABHYUDAYA NAGAR
            [E] => ABHYUDAYA EDUCATION SOCIETY, OPP. BLDG. NO. 18, ABHYUDAYA NAGAR, KALACHOWKY, MUMBAI - 400033
            [F] => 24702643
            [G] => MUMBAI
            [H] => GREATER MUMBAI
            [I] => MAHARASHTRA
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) for that. When using numerical keys, they are automatically reset so that is all you need:

```
$first = array_shift($data);
// or just: array_shift($data);
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use array_shift(). It Remove the first element from an array, and return the value of the removed element:

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");
echo array_shift($a)."<br>";
print_r ($a);
?>
```

Output will be this

```
red
Array ( [b] => green [c] => blue )
```